# Why won't my first sql statement run

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this if statement when I press a button. I also have a dropdown option form named "input". 
I am trying to make it so when the button is pressed the active field resets to '0' and then updates to "1" where it is equaled to the input field. I got the second part to work but the first doesn't work

```
//get table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  Widget";

//name variable
$result2=mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

//button begins
if(isset($_POST['Wactive'])) {
    //take the  input and set it to a variable
    $id = $_POST['input'];

    // reset the active field. This doesn't work but the sql works 
    // when I do it directly in the database
    $sql = "Update `Widget` SET Active = '0'";

    //set active to 1 where  id = the input(this works)
    $sql = "Update `Widget` SET Active = '1' WHERE `Widget_ID` = '$id'";
}
```

Comment: neither query is executed, both use the same variable name so overwrite each other

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but what *is* clear is you are wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: Changed title to make the question more clear and I am gonna try to rename the variable Dagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to filter the data. Then execute the query. You better be naming the queries with numbers to not override anything.

```
if(isset($_POST['Wactive']))
{
    $id = intval($_POST['input']);
    $sql1 = "Update `Widget` SET Active = '0'";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1);
    $sql2 = "Update `Widget` SET Active = '1' WHERE `Widget_ID` = $id";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2);
}
```

Comment: That worked. I get it now rename the variables and send it to the database.

Comment: you could use the same variable name(and save a few bytes of memory), just as long as you run the query between the two string assignments.

Comment: Ah, but "why" rename the variables, is the $64,000 question. @user3307338 ;-)

Comment: He could even use `mysqli_query()` without a variables `$query` & `$sql` as long as he knows what is he doing.

Comment: even when im sure of a query, i write it in to a string var, it makes debugging a lot easier

Answer (score 2):

`$sql` is used twice the 2nd one over writes the first so it wont run. in addition no code to execute any query is shown

Comment: If the button is clicked  then it executes the sql statements

Comment: Explanations certainly help people to understand where they went wrong; you did that. **+1** ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- it feels funny not answering with code, but some times its better not to

Comment: @Dagon I agree. Many high rep members here do just that, and the way they write it (*as you did*), gives a person a sort of "mental (*visual*) map" to figure out where the error was done. When it's embedded in your mind, one will hardly make the same mistake twice. ;-)